# How would I deploy my React.js changes on custom domain?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I just finished making a website using React.js but realized that I needed to make one more small edit.  Upon running `firebase deploy`, it keeps deploying the changes to the default hosting URL Firebase provides and not deploying changes to my custom domain (which's up and running right now).

I tried to go into the `.firebaserc` file and changing it up from:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "mywebsite-1d988"
  }
}
```

to:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "custom": "myWebsite"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this in order to edit changes to my custom domain and not firebase default domain upon running `firebase deploy`?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "not deploying changes to my custom domain"? Could you please explain in more detail how you have set up your custom domain?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec What I mean is: the changes that I'm making to code isn't being deployed to my custom domain i.e. `myWebsiteName.com`.  Instead, the changes are being deployed to the firebase default domain `mywebsite-1d988.firebaseapp.com`.  How do I change it so that it's deployed to  `myWebsiteName.com`?

Comment: If you set up your custom domain correctly with Firebase hosting, any time you run `firebase deploy` those changes will show up on both the custom domain and `yourproject.firebaseapp.com`. In fact, there is no way to deploy to one without deploying to the other. If running `firebase deploy` only deploys to `yourproject.firebaseapp.com`, it seems like your custom domain is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should note that you cannot deploy a Firebase Project to your own hosting infrastructure with the CLI (i.e. by doing `firebase deploy`).

With `firebase deploy` you **always** deploy to your Firebase project, hosted in the Firebase/Google Cloud Platform infrastructure.

What you can do in terms of "custom domain" is to **connect your custom domain to your Firebase Hosting site**, as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain.

This will **redirect** any request to your domain (e.g. `myWebsiteName.com`) to your Firebase Hosting site (`mywebsite-1d988.firebaseapp.com`), in a transparent way for the users.

Comment: Thanks for yoru answer, Renaud.  I already connected my custom domain to my FIrebase hosting site.  How would I make the changes show on `myWebsiteName.com`?  That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: In your Firebase project, after you create it with the CLI, you find a `public` folder: you should replace the content of this folder with your own files (replacing, among others, the index.html page by your home page) and redeploy with `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only hosting`

Comment: Yeah, I see the `public` folder.  But I just don't see how that would work because my files are already present on the project-level.  My apologies, I'm just very confused for some reason.

Comment: **I make the assumption that you didn't modify the hosting part of the firebase.json file**. Your files need to be served by a web server. In the case of a Firebase project, this web server is the Hosting service of Firebase. By updating the (local) files under `public` and re-reploying them your update what is served by the web server. The default URL is (and will always be) https://mywebsite-1d988.firebaseapp.com which will point to index.html. In addition, you can connect your own domain to redirect to the default URL (which will still work BTW). I hope this clarifies!

Comment: Maybe you should start with a brand new Firebase project with a default `firebase.json` file.

Comment: Other question: what do you mean by "my files are already present on the project-level"

Comment: That's correct, I never modified the hosting part of firebase.json file.  Ok for example, I want to change up the `<title></title>` tag.  I want to connect it to my own domain so that I can see that change.  I already have my own domain connected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179383/discussion-between-sp92-and-renaud-tarnec).